# Find a sequence of random variables $(X_n)$ with $\lim E(X_n^2) = 0$ but not obeying SLLN

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, examples-counterexamples, law-of-large-numbers

I am looking for some sequence of random variables $(X_n)$ such that

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E(X_n^2) = 0  $$

but such that the following **almost sure** convergence does **NOT** hold:

$$ \frac{S_n - E(S_n)}{n} \rightarrow 0$$

where the $S_n$ are the partial sums of the $X_n$.

Note: for any such sequence the convergence in probability will *always* hold; if the random variables are not correlated, so will the convergence almost surely. In particular, any counterexample must consist of correlated random variables.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Since you have convergence in probability, maybe you should think about some of the standard examples of sequences which converge in probability but not almost surely and try to find a sequence which sums to something like this. The classic example I know of is the "moving block" sequence, which looks like $1_{[0,1]},1_{[0,1/2]},1_{[1/2,1]},1_{[0,1/4]},1_{[1/4,1/2]},\dots$.

Comment: Sure, I have thought about that. But I cannot convert this example (which is just for sequences of RVs) to a corresponding result for the partial sums, which is what I find hard.

Comment: Well, if $S_n$ is the moving block sequence that I just described, does $S_n-S_{n-1}$ satisfy the desired convergence property? If not, where is it "bad"? It seems that it should only be "bad" when you jump between block lengths, if even then.

Comment: Indeed, you can take $X_n$ to be $S_n-S_{n-1}$ where $S_n$ is the moving block sequence, then $E[X_n^2]$ will be at most $\ell(n)+\ell(n-1)$ where $\ell(n)$ is the length of the block $S_n$, which decays monotonically to zero. Does this satisfy your criteria?

Comment: The division by $n$ will still make the sequence in the LLN statement go to zero almost surely, no? Perhaps multiplying by a wisely chosen factor will help.

Comment: Good point. Perhaps you can instead try to make $\frac{S_n-E[S_n]}{n}$ be the moving block sequence.

Comment: (But in that case it will be fiddly with the interplay of the $l(n)$ and the $n$. But probably possible).

Comment: Hmm, I screwed that up, because the moving block does not have mean zero, whereas $\frac{S_n-E[S_n]}{n}$ clearly does. You will need some sort of small variation on the moving block which converges in probability but not almost surely and also has mean zero. Then if $M_n$ is such a sequence then you can take $S_n=nM_n,X_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$.

Comment: A decent idea nonetheless, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm which gives you such a sequence. Let us work on the probabilised space $[0,1)$ with the Lebesgue measure.

For all $0 \leq k < n$, let $I_{k,n} := [k/n, (k+1)/n)$. Fix $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$

Start from $n = 1$, $k=0$, time $N=0$.

If $S_N < \varepsilon N$ on $I_{k,n}$, take $X_N = 1_{I_{k,n}}$.

Else :

- if $k < n-1$ : increment $k$ by $1$.
- if $k = n-1$ : increment $n$ by $1$, put $k=0$.

Rince and repeat, incrementing $N$ by $1$.

Now, for all $k,n$, we only need a finite time before $S_N \geq \varepsilon N$ on $I_{k,n}$ (the times at which these conditions are satisfied successively grow exponentially, though). Hence we will eventually increment $k$, and then $n$. Since any point in $[0,1)$ is in infinitely many $I_{k,n}$, that means that almost surely, $S_N \geq \varepsilon N$ for infinitely many $N$.

On the other hand, $\mathbb{E} (X_N) = \mathbb{E} (X_N^2)$ will converge to $0$. Hence, $\mathbb{E} (S_N)$ grows sub-linearly, so that almost surely, $S_N - \mathbb{E} (S_N) \geq \varepsilon N/2$ for infinitely many $N$s.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\left(Y_N\right)_{N\geqslant 1}$ be an i.i.d. sequence such that $\Pr\left(Y_N=1\right)=\Pr\left(Y_N=-1\right)=1/(2N)$ and $\Pr\left(Y_N=0\right)=1-1/N$. Let $\left(n_k\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of integers that will be specified later. For $n_N\leqslant i\leqslant n_{N+1}-1$, define $X_i:=Y_N$. Since each random variable $X_i$ is centered, it suffices to prove that $S_n/n$ does not converge to $0$ almost surely. Observe that 
$$
S_{n_l}=\sum_{N=1}^{l-1}\sum_{i=n_N}^{n_{N+1}-1}X_i=\sum_{N=1}^{l-1} \left(n_{N+1}-n_N\right)Y_N,
$$
hence $$
\frac{S_{n_l}}{n_l}=\left(1-\frac{n_l}{n_{l+1}}\right)Y_l+n_{l}^{-1}\sum_{N=1}^{l-2} \left(n_{N+1}-n_N\right)Y_N
$$
and thus (accounting that $\left\lvert Y_i\right\rvert\leqslant 1$), 
$$
\left\lvert \frac{S_{n_l}}{n_l}\right\rvert \geqslant \left\lvert Y_l\right\rvert-2\frac{n_l}{n_{l+1}}.
$$
If we choose the sequence $\left(n_l\right)_{l\geqslant 1}$ such that $n_l/n_{l+1}\to 0$, then 
$$
\liminf_{l\to +\infty}\left\lvert \frac{S_{n_l}}{n_l}\right\rvert \geqslant \liminf_{l\to +\infty}\left\lvert Y_l\right\rvert
$$
Using the so-called second Borel-Cantelli lemma, one can show that $\liminf_{l\to +\infty}\left\lvert Y_l\right\rvert=1$ almost surely.

Remark that  $\left(Y_l\right)_{l\geqslant 1}$ could be replaced by any sequence of centered random variables with converges to $0$ in $\mathbb L^p$ but not almost surely. This shows in particular that having $\left\lVert X_n\right\rVert_p\to 0$ for all $p$ is not sufficient for the strong law of large numbers.