# For any sequence of r .v .'s {X_n}, if $E(X_n^2) \rightarrow 0 $, then $\frac{S_n-E(S_n)}{n}\rightarrow 0$ is true in pr . but not necessarily a .e.?

Tags: probability

For any sequence of r .v .'s {X_n}, if $E(X_n^2) \rightarrow 0 $, then $\frac{S_n-E(S_n)}{n}\rightarrow 0$ is true in pr . but not necessarily a .e.? Here is my attempt.

We are given $E(X_n^2) \rightarrow 0 $ we know that $Var(X_n)\leq E(X_n^2)$ this implies $Var(X_n)\rightarrow 0$. We can conclude that $X_n\rightarrow c$      a.e.,  where c is some constant. Since $\frac{S_n}{n}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{n}$ is a cesaro sum we can conclude that $\frac{S_n}{n}\rightarrow c$ a.e, then convergence is a.e which implies in prob. My logic cant be correct since, I have shown also for a.e, the question states this does not hold always for a.e.. Where did my logic go wrong?

Comment: Here: "We can conclude that $X_n\rightarrow c$  a.e.,  where $c$ is some constant." The convergence of variance to zero implies the convergence in probability, not with probability 1.

Comment: Then how do I approach this problem?

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1216302/